# Referencing a model to define a method in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models; Networks, Lists, and Recs.

I am trying to write methods that conceptually say 'if this network has recs...' in the Network model and 'if this list has recs...' in the List model.

UPDATED: I'm getting an error in my network model on the self.recs.presence line: "undefined method `recs' for Network(id: integer, name: string):Class"

Network Model

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recs, through: :lists
  has_many :lists

  def self.network_with_recs
    self.recs.presence
  end
end
```

List Model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recs
  belongs_to :network

  def self.list_with_recs
    self.recs.presence
  end
end
```

Recs Model

```
class Rec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network, through: :lists
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Controller

```
  def index
    @recs = Rec.to_do
    @lists = List.all
    @networks = Network.network_with_recs.all
  end
```

Comment: How are you calling it in the controller? Please post the controller code. Also full error log.

Comment: Added my controller code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to guess:

**list.rb**
You have to add class method with `self`

```
def self.network_with_recs
  recs = joins(:recs)
  if recs.present?
     all
  else
     nil
  end
end
```

**Controller**
remove your object method `.all`

```
def index
  @recs = Rec.to_do
  @lists = List.all
  @networks = Network.network_with_recs
end
```

Comment: did you mean the network.rb file above instead of list.rb?

Comment: Yes, I did. You can copy in your network.rb. Let me know when It works

Comment: I believe this worked.  Is there a way to put an additional condition on the recs based on a recs attribute (such as a true / false column).  In other words.  network_with_recs = recs that belong to that network that also have a true/false column = to true?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's hard to understand. Do you have a detail?

Comment: I ended up writing a separate question for it since it's unrelated from this one and you successfully answered this one > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672817/error-when-trying-to-define-a-method-that-references-another-model/32673369?noredirect=1#comment53198457_32673369  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an ***instance method*** on a ***class*** like this `@networks = Network.network_with_recs.all`. If you want to call it like that, then you should make it as a ***class method***. And also there is no `present`, you should make it as `presence` if I'm not wrong

```
def self.network_with_recs
  self.recs.presence
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I made it the update in the model.  The new error is "undefined method `recs' for Network(id: integer, name: string):Class"

Comment: @brad Can you post your full error log in the question?

Comment: @brad What happens when you change this line `self.recs.presence` to `recs.presence`?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `recs' for Network(id: integer, name: string):Class on that same line.

Comment: @brad You need to change `belongs_to :network, through: :lists` to `belongs_to :network` in `Rec` model and call it `self.recs.presence`

Comment: Updated to belongs_to :network, same error.  What are you saying should be called self.recs.presence?  I have that in my network model per above.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: @brad Now try removing `.all` in this line `@networks = Network.network_with_recs.all`

Comment: It still is saying my call of .recs in the network model is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As the interpreter correctly states: There is no method `present` on active record relations - Maybe you wanted to call `present?` - for `Enumerables` you can use the more explicit `any?`