# Unsuccessfully attempting to define a method that references another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lists have many `recs` and `recs` belong to `lists`.  I am trying to define a method in the `list` model, called "eat_lists_with_to_do_recs".

I want this method to include LISTS, that (1) have recs (2) have recs where done=false and (3) recs where rec_type = 'eats'

For some reason, the method I wrote below is not filtering out lists that don't meet those 3 conditions.  When I call the method in the view it returns lists where done = TRUE and rec_type doesn't = eats.

Additional info - networks have many `lists` and `recs`, as you can see in that model.  `Lists` and `recs` belong to `network`

List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recs
  belongs_to :network

   def eat_lists_with_to_do_recs
    recs.where("done = ? AND rec_type = ?", false, 'Eats')
   end
end
```

Rec model

```
class Rec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
  belongs_to :list
end
```

View (3rd line of actual code is error)

```
<%= link_to 'Add a New Rec', new_rec_type_url %></br>
  <% if @networks_with_recs.present? %>
    <% @networks_with_recs.each do |network| %></br>

        <%= network.name %></br>

        <% network.lists.each(&:eat_lists_with_to_do_recs).each do |list| %>
          <%= list.name %></br>

          <% list.recs.each do |rec| %>
            <%= rec.name.split(',').first %>
            <%= rec.notes %>
            <%= rec.done %>
            <%= link_to 'Done', marked_as_done_url(rec), method: :patch %></br>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', rec, method: :delete %></br>
          <% end %>

        <% end %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Additional info -

Controller

```
  def index
    @networks_with_recs = Network.networks_with_recs
  end
```

Network Model

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :recs, through: :lists
  has_many :lists

def self.networks_with_recs
  recs = joins(:recs)
  if recs.present?
     all
  else
     nil
  end
end


end
```

Comment: Not the error you mention in your question, but your `network.list.flat_map(...).each ...` iterates over an array of `recs` not `lists`, are you aware of that?

Comment: I was not aware of that.  I updated my code above to the latest.  My issue now is that the results in the view include 'true' recs.  This should be weeded out by the method i defined in the list model that I'm subsequently using in the view.  THanks for looking

Comment: The last your condition is `recs.where("done = ? AND rec_type = ?", 'false', 'Eats')`but before your condition was `recs.where("done = ? AND rec_type = ?", 'true', 'Eats')`. What is your right condition?

Comment: False is the correct condition.  I had it wrong at first by accident.  Code above is fully updated.  The lists and recs are showing up, but it's not filtering out recs who have done=true.

Comment: Before going to the next step, I thought, It needs to be fixed in the relational of table associations. In network.rb, `has_many :recs, through: :lists` changes into `has_many :recs` without `through: :lists` because of one to many association. Is that true?

Comment: Is the intention to only show those lists that have recs according to your filter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`return nil if recs.blank?`

Eventually, you are calling `each` on the return value in your view:

`network.lists.eat_lists_with_to_do_recs.each do |list|`

But `nil` does not respond to `each`, so in the case where a `List` has no `Recs`, your application will raise an exception.

The solution is to simply remove that line:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recs
  belongs_to :network

  def eat_lists_with_to_do_recs
    recs.where("done = ? AND rec_type = ?", 'false', 'Eats')
  end
end
```

In this case, `where` will return an empty collection, which is fine, since calling `each` on an empty collection will not do anything, it will just silently return.

This is related to a concept called the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). In this case, an empty collection is the null object for a collection of `Recs`, and it invokes a standard behaviour (in this case nothing.)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately it's still showing lists that have recs where done=true and rec_type <> eats.  I did remove that line and it has not errored on me, which is good.  I want that method to come up with lists that a) have recs b) recs where done = false and c) rec_type = eats.  For some reason it's not filtering those 2 things.  Something is not right with eat_lists_with_to_do_recs

Comment: What type is `done` in your database? A `boolean`? Try removing the quotes around `false` in your query, and see if it helps: `recs.where("done = ? AND rec_type = ?", false, 'Eats')`

Comment: Tried that - still returned values of true.

Comment: I'm looking into whether that method returns recs, not lists.  I want it to return lists that have recs with those conditions, not recs.